Programmable swap on Jupiter
I submit an jupiter swap transaction, it gets signed and gives a tx hash, but on solscan it says "transaction not found". if anyone has fixed this problem please share your code if possible or if you can help out.

Can you show your code where you send the transaction? Note that having a transaction signature doesn't necessarily mean it's been sent, only that it's been signed by the fee payer. It still needs to be sent to the network, which you may be missing, but without seeing your code I don't know if that's the case here.

@CallumM how do i share?
github link?

Github repo/gist, or codesandbox/replit are probably the easiest yep. Or add a code snippet to the question.
